# WPF Custom Modal Dialog using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dialog, user-controls, overlay

### Issue

I am struggling to pass the result of which button was pressed from my `CustomDialogUserControl.xaml.cs` to my `CustomDialogService.cs`.

### Background

I am able to use the `MessageBox.Show` through my `CustomDialogService.cs` and everything works great and looks like this:

[image]

I created my own `CustomDialogUserControl` to achieve an overlay window by using `x:Name="MainGrid"` in my application window and programmatically adding a child of my user control when the dialog is required.

[image]

I am just struggling to implement the functionality of how to pass which button was pressed to my `DialogService.cs`

### Project Structure

[image]

### MainWindowViewModel.cs

The view model is very simple. It inherits from `ViewModelBase` which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I am also using a basic `RelayCommand` implentation. When one of the buttons is pressed I call my `CustomDialogService`.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _text = "This is my MainWindowViewModel";

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set 
        { 
            _text = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand OpenDefaultCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand OpenCustomCommand { get; set; }

    ICustomDialogService _customDialogService;

    public MainWindowViewModel(ICustomDialogService customDialogService)
    {
        OpenDefaultCommand = new RelayCommand(OpenDefault, CanOpen);
        OpenCustomCommand = new RelayCommand(OpenCustom, CanOpen);
        _customDialogService = customDialogService;
    }

    // Uses default message box
    private void OpenDefault(object obj)
    {
        var result = _customDialogService.ShowOKDialogDefault("My title", "My message");

        if (result == CustomDialogResult.OK)
            Text = "Default OK was clicked";
        else
            Text = "Default Cancel was clicked";
    }

    // Uses custom user control
    private void OpenCustom(object obj)
    {
        var result = _customDialogService.ShowOKDialogCustom("My title", "My message");

        if (result == CustomDialogResult.OK)
            Text = "Custom OK was clicked";
        else
            Text = "Custom Cancel was clicked";
    }

    private bool CanOpen(object arg)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

### CustomDialogService.cs

This is where I am having an issue getting a result from my `CustomDialogUserControl` which button was pressed. All works great in the `ShowOKDialogDefault` that uses the built in `MessageBox`.

```
public enum CustomDialogResult
{
    OK, Yes, No, Cancel
}

public class CustomDialogService : ICustomDialogService
{
    public CustomDialogResult ShowOKDialogDefault(string title, string message)
    {
        // Uses default MessageBox
        var result = MessageBox.Show(message, title, MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

        if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            return CustomDialogResult.OK;
        else
            return CustomDialogResult.Cancel;
    }

    public CustomDialogResult ShowOKDialogCustom(string title, string message)
    {
        // Uses custom user control
        var customDialog = new CustomDialogUserControl(title, message);
        ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).MainGrid.Children.Add(customDialog);

        // --- THE ISSUE ---
        // How do I return the result here telling me which button was pressed in my User Control?
        return CustomDialogResult.Cancel;

    }

    // TODO: Implement other dialogs
    public CustomDialogResult ShowYesNoDialog(string title, string message)
    {
        return CustomDialogResult.Cancel;
    }
}
```

### CustomDialogUserControl.xaml.cs

This is my custom user control. I am trying to follow MVVM and I read that using code behind for a user control is acceptable. I am using dependency properties to bind the `Title` and the `Message`. The problem is, I have click events for the buttons but I honestly can't figure out how to return the result back to my `CustomDialogService`

```
public partial class CustomDialogUserControl : UserControl
{
    public CustomDialogUserControl(string title, string message)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Title = title;
        Message = message;
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(CustomDialogUserControl));


    public string Message
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MessageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MessageProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MessageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Message", typeof(string), typeof(CustomDialogUserControl));

    private void OK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // My issue
        var result = CustomDialogResult.OK;
        ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).MainGrid.Children.Remove(this);
    }

    private void Cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // My issue
        var result = CustomDialogResult.Cancel;
        ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).MainGrid.Children.Remove(this);
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Feels like the solution will be simple but I've just spent so much time on this already I thought I'd ask the community for help.

If anything else stands out in my code that breaks the MVVM pattern please let me know.

### Update based on reply from user2250152

Thanks for the reply - I tried this approach myself but when I open my dialog the `Text` property in `MainWindowViewModel` changes to OK before I press any buttons. See the snapshot below:

[image]

These are the changes I made to the code per the reply for future reference:

### CustomDialogUserControl.xaml.cs

```
public CustomDialogResult Result { get; set; }

    private void OK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // My issue
        Result = CustomDialogResult.OK;
        ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).MainGrid.Children.Remove(this);
    }

    private void Cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // My issue
        Result = CustomDialogResult.Cancel;
        ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).MainGrid.Children.Remove(this);
    }
```

### CustomDialogService.cs

```
public CustomDialogResult ShowOKDialogCustom(string title, string message)
    {
        // Uses custom user control
        var customDialog = new CustomDialogUserControl(title, message);
        ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).MainGrid.Children.Add(customDialog);

        return customDialog.Result;
    }
```

Comment: MVVM and dialogs handling in view model component don't go together. MVVM requires the view model to be unaware of a view, which means it must be absolute passive towards the view, which means the view model should never trigger dialogs actively. You even have implemented a logic to decide what kind of dialog to show. You even create dialog instances to show them directly. This is not MVVM.

Comment: You basically only have to toggle the visibility of your custom dialog from collapsed to visible. The related logic must be in the view. Then attach a command to the close or accept button. This command should be defined in the view model that is the DataContext of the UserControl.

Comment: _"I am trying to follow MVVM and I read that using code behind for a user control is acceptable."_ - absolutely. Then why did you decide to show the dialog from the view model instead from the view's code-behind? Don't do it.

Comment: @BionicCode - what would be your alternative suggestion to keep the purists happy?  Sometimes pragmatism is better than extreme ideology.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new property `Result` of type `CustomDialogResult` in `CustomDialogUserControl.xaml.cs` and assign the result in `OK_Click` and `Cancel_Click`.

```
public CustomDialogResult Result { get; set; }
...
private void OK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Result = CustomDialogResult.OK;
    ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).MainGrid.Children.Remove(this);
}

private void Cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Result = CustomDialogResult.Cancel;
    ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).MainGrid.Children.Remove(this);
}
```

Read the result in `CustomDialogService.cs`

```
public CustomDialogResult ShowOKDialogCustom(string title, string message)
{
    // Uses custom user control
    var customDialog = new CustomDialogUserControl(title, message);
    ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).MainGrid.Children.Add(customDialog);
    return customDialog.Result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I've updated my question with your suggestion. However, I am still having an issue with getting the correct state through to the main view model using that approach. See the snapshot in the update to see what I mean.

Comment: @TheEngineer Try to debug your code. Probably when you call ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).MainGrid.Children.Add(customDialog); it doesn't block thread and ShowOKDialogCustom ended before you click on OK or Cancel button. Maybe using WaitHandle to wait until some button in custom dialog is pressed can help. Or create a custom window inherited from Window and call ShowDialog on it.

Comment: I see what you mean with the WaitHandle - I'll give that a try and update the post if I get it to work. In terms of the second approach where you inherit from a Window - will this work in my case? I tried to do something like this myself but the problem is my dialog is not a window, it's just a user control with a transparent rectangle added to the main grid. When I tried inheriting from Window, I was getting the Window border and buttons added to my user control.

Comment: Probably calling `(MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow` from the view model, should get your attention that there were some bad design choices made, that obviously violate the MVVM pattern.

Comment: @BionicCode I am not calling `(MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow` in my View Model but in my DialogService, the ViewModel only knows about the IDialogService interface. I thought this approach maintains the separation of concerns?

Comment: @TheEngineer This is a wrong perception as you are simply "hiding" the dependency. Two examples:

Comment: 1) You have this nice folder structure to provide some logical separation. You have a "Views" folder and a "ViewModels" folder. I hope you agree that a `UserControl` is a UI object and belongs logically to the view, right?. Therefore, we move `CustomDialogUserControl` to the "Views" folder. Now we push it one step further and move the "Views" folder to its own project called "UI". Now we are left with two projects the main project and the "UI" project, where the view models and the "service" class remain in the main project.

Comment: Now in order to be able to use the service your Main project must reference (know) the UI project to reference the `CustomDialogUserControl` class. Here you can see that you have created a dependency that points from view model to the view. More worse, services are considered to be model. This means your model is baically directly linked to the view because it instantiates a `UserControl`.

Comment: 2) Let's say your `MainViewModel` would have a constructor where it calls `Window.Show()`. I guess you would agree that this violates MVVM - that's why you introduced the service. Ok, service aside. Now we refactor and move the violating code to its own method `ShowDialog()`. Does this fix the problem? No, because `MainViewModel` is calling it? Then lets move the method into its own class and name this class DialogService. Now when MainViewModel call DialogService.ShowDialog has this changed anything? No.

Comment: The view model still calls or shows a dialog. You don't want to have UI logic in your view model class. You don't want the view model to actively participate in UI logic at all. All it does is to add a layer between view and model. The trick is that the view model does not actively interact with the view.

Comment: Other point of view. MVVM divides the application into three components: view, view model and model. Don't think about files when thinking about MVVM. It's an archgitectural pattern and that talks about components (logical groups like folders) that contain classes. Now where do you put the service to? View? Then the view model using the view would be too obvious. View model? Since the service references UI objects and actively interacts with the UI this would mean the violating code is still in the view model, just moved to a class we named service. To the model? Definitely not.

Comment: So everywhere we move the service to, it violates MVVM because the view model uses it. The solution: do not have the view model participate in UI logic. Move the logic to the view. That's soo simple. You don't need a pseudo service. Remember, we are not talking about class level dependencies. Introducing a interface is called Dependency Inversion Principle. MVVM removes any dependency from view model to view. The result is that no class in the view model depends on a class of the UI. For example changing the dialog class should not affect any view model class.

Comment: You said that you can use code-behind, then why don't you do it? The point is changing your code leads to new responsibilities. For some reason you find it difficult to have the view showing the dialog. You want the view model to handle it. The point is you would never introduce a "service" so that the model can control the view model. This is simply the wrong flow. Same applies to view model and view. View model just exposes data or data models.

Comment: Your MainViewModel could expose another view model that you can use to set it as DataContext for your dialog. Then those two view models can happily communicate with each other to exchange data. Let the dialog use a ICommand on one of the view models to close/accept the user input.

Comment: You can use events to notify other view models about the changed state. No need for a service. Dialog stays in view. Like any other control. You would never start such thing for a ListBox or a ComboBox. A dialog is nothing different.

Comment: @BionicCode thank you for the thorough reply! - I've read it a couple of times and I do kind of see your point. I am just still a little bit lost as the course I am doing on Pluralsight "Building an Enterprise App with WPF, MVVM..." does exactly what I have done. The only difference is instead of calling a custom user control it uses the built in `MessageBox.Show` also inside the implementation of `CustomDialogService` that inherits from `ICustomDialogService`.

Comment: @TheEngineer There are many wrong examples out there. The dialog "service" works because it uses _Dependency Inversion_: because of the interface you can test your view model and mock the "service" - loose coupling. But it does violate MVVM, I hope I could show this. The point is the whole view model actively handles controls or is engaged with user interaction (dialog views). I always feel astonished why people think that controlling this service is domain of view model and not view. It makes no sense.

Comment: The view is the component where views are created. We do it all the time when we create the items of a `ListBox`. We define data models and expose them to the `ListBox`, which creates the actual controls (item containers) based on a `DataTemplate`. You can use the same `DataTemplate` approach a.k.a. view-model-first to let the view instantiate the `UserControl`. This even more elegant than a service - and it respects the responsibilities of the MVVM components.

Comment: At least you should call the service from code-behind. Any flow, where the view model has to show dialogs must be re-designed to give the view model back its view unawareness. The data binding is a concept developed by Microsoft for the only reason to realize a stricter/improved MVP pattern, which they named MVVM. Dependency inversion is much older, but obviously is not enough to provide the unidirectional dependency between view and view model, while still being able to send data from view model to view.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `Result` property to your `CustomDialogUserControl.xaml.cs` class and set this one in the `Click` event handlers for the buttons as per your update.

> I tried this approach myself but when I open my dialog the Text property in MainWindowViewModel changes to OK before I press any buttons.

Since the default value of `Result` is `CustomDialogResult.OK`, or whatever the first option of your `enum` is called, you should either change the type of the property to `Nullable<Result>` (`Result?`) or add an `Undefined` option to the `enum`.

You can then correctly set the `Text` property based on the value of the property, e.g.:

```
private void OpenDefault(object obj)
{
    var result = _customDialogService.ShowOKDialogDefault("My title", "My message");

    Text = string.Empty;
    if (result.HasValue)
    {
        if (result.Value == CustomDialogResult.OK)
            Text = "Default OK was clicked";
        else
            Text = "Default Cancel was clicked";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried both of your suggestions but this did not fix the problem. I did some more digging and found an answer [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36516/WPF-Modal-Dialog). The problem was I need to block the thread and wait until the user responds to the button click before returning from the method.